# Snowflake - How to use array_construct() in bulk insert for snowflake node sdk

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake. Currently using snowflake node js sdk to insert data in to snowflake tables. Could any one suggest how to use array_construct() function in bulk insert while using snowflake node js sdk?

Answer (score 0):

ARRAY_CONSTRUCT() function is not used for bulk inserting. It's for building an array object based on input values.

```
select array_construct(10, 20, 30);
```

The above command will return only 1 row which contains an array object.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct.html

For bulk inserting on nodeJs, you need to create a JavaScript array and pass it to INSERT command:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#binding-array-for-bulk-insert

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array